# How to open a file in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, file-io

Having difficulty opening a csv file in pandas, I have tried:

```
data = pd.read_csv("/home/me/Programming/data/sample.csv")
```

That did not work, so I tried:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()

data = pd.read_csv(cwd + "sample.csv")
```

and that doesn't work either, just says that file does not exist, but it's there in the file manager clear as day.

Comment: `pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')` will work if `f = open('/path/to/file.csv')` works. So make sure you can open your file using `open()` function...

Comment: as for me,     os.path.join(cwd, "sample.csv") is better then `cwd + "sample.csv"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`os.getcwd()` return the current working directory without trailing path separtor.

You should use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of `+` to correctly join paths:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(cwd, 'sample.csv'))
```

BTW, there's no need to specify full path of current working directory; just specify `sample.csv` should be enough:

```
data = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
```

Make sure the file `sample.csv` is in the current working directory.

Comment: Thank you, I thought as much and as it were, I was in the wrong directory when trying to prototype the line in the python shell. I didn't know the os.path.join, and I think I need to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the whole path you can make a folder named for example "CSV reader" and then save the python file in the same location either inside or outside the file "CSV reader". If you save the file inside the "CSV reader" folder then the code will be:-

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
```

If you save the python file outside the folder then the code would look like:-

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("CSV reader/sample.csv")
```

And the work gets easier now.